# Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release 403 Forbidden

Tags: updates

Software updater in MATE 19.10 failed to download repository information so I ran:
sudo apt-get update

I received the following error:
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release
  403  Forbidden

So I uninstalled Etcher in the software boutique hoping that would fix the issue. I restarted the computer. Then I ran sudo apt-get update again and received the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **package** is the software bundle.

A **source** is one location on the internet that you packages from. Your system has several sources. You can see your lists of sources in /etc/apt. Sources often look like URLs (you can paste them into a web browser). You will usually see a bunch of packages or a directory tree if you do that.

Your error is with a SOURCE, so uninstalling a package won't affect anything. Instead, look at that source in a web browser, and try to find the package you are looking for.

Iv this case, if you follow the source links down the rabbit-hole (https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian/dists/stable/etcher/binary-amd64/), you will eventually see that links in that directory are indeed 403 Forbidden.

This means that the etcher admins have mis-configured their repository. Please contact them and let them know.

Comment: More likely this is caused by Etcher's BinTray account or repository not having anything in it for that target anymore for whatever reason.  Most of those repo folders are controlled by BinTray which is a third party service :P

Comment: So, dumb question, can I just delete the etcher files (they appear to be plain text files) in the source.list.d folder? I have no interest in getting Etcher working again at this point.

Comment: Yes, indeed you can delete those etcher-specific text files in /etc/sources.list.d/. Afterward, run a `sudo apt update` and check for any errors.

Comment: Deleting the files in the /etc/apt/source.list.d folder fixed the issue.